# Website auto zoom on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I have a non-responsive site with a fixed body size. Because of the size of the screen, when I see it on my phone I have to zoom out to see the whole page.
How can I have my page automatically zoomed in/out to fit the screen?

Comment: Use em instead of px for the size.

Answer (score 3):

In a `meta` tag used the property `content="initial-scale={zoomlvl}"`.

- `Initial-scale` configurs the default zoom.
- `Initial-scale` valus is between 1.0 and 10.0.

Example :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=5.0">
```